# genrsa key fails if generated under Debian 12 vs generated under Debian 11

Tags: openssl

I have a script which generates certificates and a key for an embedded product which uses mbedtls for its TLS communications.

I am generating the key using openssl as follows:

openssl genrsa -out myfile.key 2048

If I generate this key using Debian 11, the embedded processor running mbedtls can load the key without issue, however if I generate the key under Debian 12 the embedded application (mbedtls) says it cannot load the key.

Is there some setting on Debian 12 which is different regards openssl which could make the key generation incompatible?

The files look basically the same, the Debian 12 key file is a few bytes larger than the Debian 11 key file (1704 vs 1679)

Comment: Did you update latest Debian 12 this month?

Comment: Does 'look the same' include the BEGIN/END label lines? 11=buster has OpenSSL 1.1.1n and 1.1.x (down) `genrsa` writes 'traditional' (PKCS1) format with BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY, while 12=bookworm has 3.0.11 and 3.0 (up) writes PKCS8 format with BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY -- which is a different format, although [this doc](https://mbed-tls.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem/) suggests mbedtls supports both, although I don't know if any coding is involved. In 3.0 try `genrsa -traditional` to get old=PKCS1 format.

Comment: Thanks, the -traditional switch worked. The PKCS8 should be supported by our mbedtls, not sure why it isn't but you have enabled me to get our script working on Debian 12